# Any ideal way to calculate the travel time by two different postal code through mapquest api?

Tags: api, dictionary, duration, postal-code, mapquest

There is address provided in column database but any ways able to calcalute time of two distance using postal code? Supposed we used mapquest api.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method to find the distance between two locations is the route matrix which only returns time and distance. I'm no spreadsheet wizard that can provide a method to call the api, but here is a sample request for a route matrix to find the distance between two US zip codes.

www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/routematrix?key=KEY&from=80202+US&to=80220+US